# Why isn't cv2.imwrite() saving my numpy array image in the specified folder?

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, opencv

```
import cv2

for label in labels:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    print('Collecting images for {}'.format(label))
    time.sleep(5)
    for imgnum in range(number_imgs):
        print('Collecting image {}'.format(imgnum))
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        imgname = os.path.join(IMAGES_PATH,label,label+'.'+'{}.jpg'.format(str(uuid.uuid1())))
        
        cv2.imwrite(imgname, frame)
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        
        
        time.sleep(2)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I ran the above code there was no error while it was compiling. The problem is that the cv2.imwrite() function is not saving the images i have just collected. I have checked the return value of imgname for my image path and its correct. The names i used to name the labels were written in amharic language format ( For example one of my labels name was 'ቤት' meaning house) but i do not think that would be a problem because it did not bring any error while the folders for the labels were created.

Comment: First, you don't need to define `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` inside the for loop. You only need to define the `VideoCapture` object once so it's better to write it before the `for` loop. Does the image shows up when you run the code, `cv2.imshow('frame', frame)` should do that, if the image is not showing up and it is not saved to the specified location then check if your inner `for` loop is running. Where do you define `number_imgs` variable, if it is 0 then the inner `for` loop won't run and you won't see any image shown or saved.

Comment: Please start with ANSI characters for your folder and file names. If this fails, too, please print out the full path `imgname` that is passed to `imwrite` and share it with us.

Comment: Did you try an isolated test, where you imread and display an image file and write a  'ቤት.png' and a 'a.png' to the same folder? If that works you know that the characters are not a problem. One important thing is that imwrite will not create directories, so make sure they already exist (it will not throw an exception or give an error if it couldn't write!).

Comment: when i used English alphabets it worked well and it saved the images successfully. The problem is when i name the labels with Amharic alphabet languages like the one i just mentioned above "ቤት.jpg"

Comment: Are you able to write a .txt file with those characters in the filensme, using OS functions? It yes, write an image with ANSI characters and inwrite and then use os function to rename the written file to your target name.